# Memory Usage when using to_sql not dropping

Tags: python

I am looping through a file to try to push it to a microsoft sql server.  Every time it runs to_sql it begins to fill up memory.  Is there an easy fix anyone knows of?

I tried using gc.collect() and setting the data frame to "" would fix the issue, but it has not.  I also tried putting the process in a function.

Below is my function.  It's pretty straightforward.  I have seen a few other answers on stack on this, but so far none have provided a solution.

from sqlalchemy import types, create_engine, event
import pandas as pd
import gc

def pushtosql(df,sql_table,append='replace'):
#Send to SQL
from lookups import usernames, passwords, general_lookups, dev_lookups, prod_lookups
ms_server_name=server_name
ms_db_name=db_name
ms_user=username
ms_password=password

```
conn =  "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER="+ms_server_name+";DATABASE="+ms_db_name+";UID="+ms_user+";PWD="+ms_password+""
quoted = quote_plus(conn)
new_con = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted)
engine = create_engine(new_con)

@event.listens_for(engine, 'before_cursor_execute')
def receive_before_cursor_execute(conn, cursor, statement, params, context, executemany):
    if executemany:
        cursor.fast_executemany = True
df.to_sql(name=sql_table, schema='SCHEMA', con=engine, if_exists=append,index=False)
df = "" 
gc.collect()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no real solution unfortunately as it's an underlying Python issue of how the Memory is utilized (I have the same issue btw) 
It helps to chunk the data before the insert though (I do it in 300k chunks):

```
if len(dataframe_events) > chunksize:
    chunk_counter = 1
    chunk_count_total = math.ceil(len(dataframe_events) / chunksize)
    list_df_events = [dataframe_events[i:i + chunksize] for i in range(0, dataframe_events.shape[0], chunksize)]
    for df_tmp in list_df_events:
        log.info(f"Inserting Chunk {chunk_counter} of {chunk_count_total}")
        df_tmp.to_sql(name=config['DB']['EventTable'], con=connection, if_exists='append', index=False)
        chunk_counter += 1
else:
    dataframe_events.to_sql(name=config['DB']['EventTable'], con=connection, if_exists='append', index=False)
```